# Do Interrogative Negative forms in the simple present tense imply only two situations?

Tags: tenses, negation

Is it correct to say that, in English, when you use the Present Simple tense in the Interrogative Negative form you are either implying the negative or just confirming the affirmative (depending on the order of "Do", "subject" and "not"), but no other possibility?

Like in the scene of The Lord Of the Ring - The Return of the King, when Eowyn is talking to Aragorn just before he leaves to see the dead army in the mountain.

Eowyn: "You cannot abandon the men. We need you here."
Aragorn: "Why have you come?"
Eowyn: "Do you not know?"

In this last line, given the context, she is clearly implying that she thinks he knows she loves him, and thus, she is asking it just to confirm it (as I understood it). But then, if she had used the other form "Don't you know?", it would change the meaning, as she would appear to be asking it to really have a first idea on his feelings, not presuming anything. Then my question is: can the Interrogative Negative have only these two possibilities?

Comment: I don't think the nuance you find between the two forms is actually present.

Comment: Pretty sure [there's a duplicate](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15362/191178) but it may have hard to decide which ones are best.

Comment: From @TimR there is no implicational difference between "Don't you know?" and "Do you no know?" but there is a difference between "Do you know?" and "Do you not know?" They both ask the same question, but the first implies they might not know, whereas the second implies that they probably do (or should) know.

Comment: Note that the language in LOTR is consciously archaic. Modern English speakers would ask "Don't you know?" Using an uncontracted negative with _do_-support is useful when there is another construction to feed into, like "Do you not believe him, or are you just dubious?" But mostly _don't_ is the question word to use. If somebody's using archaic language, all grammar bets are off.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say that "Do you not know?" is archaism but it is in a formal register. It certainly isn't   **Aragon: *Whydja come?* Eowyn: *Dontcha know?***